# Prolog translation

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create simple prolog program which have simple rules,

```
means(you,i):-!.
means(are,'am not'):-!.
means(is,'is not'):-!.
means(english,german):-!.
means('i am','why, are, you'):-!.
means(do,no):-!.
means(X,X).
translate([], []).
translate([H1,H2|T1],[H3|T3]):-
    (H1==i,H2==am)->(means('i am',H3),translate(T1,T3));(
                                   means(H1,H3),translate(T1,T3)).
```

example

```
?- translate([you,are,a,child],A).
A = [I,am,not,a,child].
?- translate([do,you,know,english],A).
A = [no,I,know,german].
?- translate([I,am,bored],A).
A = [why,are,you,bored].
?- translate([this,is,a,book],A).
A = [this,is,not,a,book].
```

But when i run 
`translate([you,are,a,child],A).`
it returns as 
`A = [i, a].`
Cannot find the mistake.

Comment: Note that `'why, are, you'` is not the same as `[why, are, you]`. The commas really serve no purpose in that context. You get `[i, a]` as the translation of `[you, are, a child]` because `you` translates to `i`, your code skips `are` since your phrase doesn't start with `i, am, ...`, `a` translates to `a` by default and `child` is skipped since, again, it's not of the form `i, am, ...`. That part of your logic is fundamentally incorrect: always skipping the second word if the two words are not `i, am`.

Comment: @lurker but in documentation it says if->then;else shouldnt i just go with else ?

Comment: yes it does, but your "else" clause ignores `H2`.

Comment: @lurker how can i “unignore H2”

Comment: `means(H1,H3),translate([H2|T1],T3)` instead of `means(H1,H3),translate(T1,T3)`.

Comment: @lurker it Throws false because of ( i think ) it can not find both H1 and H2 in the last call

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer for your question but a code review that's too long for a comment.

The code for your `means/2` predicate uses (1) cuts and (2) a catchall clause:

```
means(X,X).
```

I assume the cuts are used to prevent backtracking into the catchall clause when one of the earlier clauses apply? You can avoid both the cuts and the catchall clause by rewriting your code as:

```
means(you, i).
means(are, 'am not').
means(is, 'is not').
means(english, german).
means('i am', 'why, are, you').
means(do, no).

translate([], []).
translate([H1, H2| T1], [H3| T3]) :-
    (   H1 == i, H2 == am ->
        means('i am', H3),
        translate(T1, T3)
    ;   means(H1, H3) ->
        translate(T1, T3)
    ;   H3 = H1,
        translate(T1, T3)
    ).
```

Of course, you still need to fix the code as per the other comments.

Comment: İs it big problem ?

Comment: Cuts may restrict the solutions that you can generate, preventing other uses of your predicates. Catchall clauses may prevent good indexing of your code by the Prolog system. Assume, for example, a `means(you, X)` goal, which unifies with the heads of two clauses. That means that a choice-point will be created only to be discarded by the cut in the first clause. This is costly, hurting performance. In the revised code I posted, Prolog internal indexing mechanism will select the only clause that applies without trying the  other ones and without creating spurious choice-points.

Comment: but without means(X,X). i cannot print another characters except in rules

Comment: I cannot comment in use cases outside the code you posted. But you can take my reply as generic advise and apply it only where it's appropriate.